# Debian preseed swap label

Tags: debian, preseed

I'm preseeding my Debian installation quite successfully, but I have one problem. I want my `swap` partition to be labeled, but the installer is ignoring the `label { }` element. The partion is created, it has an `UUID`, but I want to mount by labels (multisystem environment with Windows, etc.)
Other labels are created without problems.

I'm preseeding Debian Stretch.

```
d-i partman/early_command \
        string sfdisk --wipe-partitions always --delete /dev/sda 2 3 4
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/init_automatically_partition select biggest_free

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                       \
    lk-part ::                                              \
            2000 2000 2000 linux-swap                       \
                    $primary{ }                             \
                    method{ swap }                          \
                    format{ }                               \
                    label{ SWAPPART }                       \
            .                                               \
            50000 50000 50000 xfs                           \
                    $primary{ }                             \
                    method{ format }                        \
                    format{ }                               \
                    use_filesystem{ }                       \
                    filesystem{ xfs }                       \
                    mountpoint{ / }                         \
                    label{ LKLINUX }                        \
            .                                               \
            40000 40100 -1 xfs                              \
                    $primary{ }                             \
                    method{ format }                        \
                    format{ }                               \
                    use_filesystem{ }                       \
                    filesystem{ xfs }                       \
                    mountpoint{ /tmp }                      \
                    label{ TEMPFS }                         \
            .
d-i partman/mount_style select label
```

Does anyone know why the label on `swap` is ignored?

After the installation, when I manually do:

```
swapoff /dev/sda2
mkswap --label SWAPPART /dev/sda2
swapon /dev/sda2
```

the label is present and displayed for example by `blkid`.

Best Regards
Kamil

Comment: What outputs are you listing? It is not clear that your label is not being accepted as everything you have posted shows your desired label being   used.

Comment: It is my `preseed.cfg` file, it is my config to be set on my disks during installation. After the installation partitions are created properly, but labels are set only on `/` and `/tmp`, but not on `swap`.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this question is rather old, but just in case someone stumbles upon this, here is the answer:

The reason for the swap label being ignored is that the installer uses mkswap from busybox, which cannot set labels. [To verify this just boot into a netboot installer, switch to the second console (Alt+F2) and look at the mkswap binary.]

As a workaround I have created a debian package luh-label-swap which on install reformats the swap partitions (via preinstall script) preserving the UUIDs and setting labels swap, swap1, swap2 etc. and fixes the fstab entries as well.

You may find the package in our repository: http://ubuntu.repo.uni-hannover.de/ubuntu/pool/pub/l/luh-label-swap/ see below for the relevant code.

It's not a very elegant solution, but works for us. :)

Regards,
Robert

These are the relevant parts:

**debian/postinst**

```
#!/bin/sh
# postinst script for luh-label-swap

set -e

# [..]

case "$1" in
    configure)
            cp -a /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.dpkg-old
            /usr/lib/luh-label-swap/label-swap
            echo "modified /etc/fstab; old version saved as /etc/fstab.dpkg-old."
    ;;
    abort-upgrade|abort-remove|abort-deconfigure)
    ;;
    *)
        echo "postinst called with unknown argument \`$1'" >&2
        exit 1
    ;;
esac

# dh_installdeb will replace this with shell code automatically
# generated by other debhelper scripts.

#DEBHELPER#

exit 0
```

**/usr/lib/luh-label-swap/label-swap**

```
#!/bin/bash
# /usr/lib/luh-label-swap/label-swap
#

FSTAB="/etc/fstab"

IAM="$(basename $0)"
unset NO
swapoff -a
for UUID in $(egrep '^UUID=[0-9a-f-]+\s+[[:alpha:]]+\s+swap' "$FSTAB" \
                | sed 's/^UUID=\([0-9a-f-]*\).*/\1/'); do
        echo "$IAM: found swap with UUID=$UUID"
        DEVICE="$(blkid -U "$UUID")"
        if [ -n "$DEVICE" ]; then
                LABEL="swap$NO"
                test -v $NO && NO+=1 || declare -i NO=1
                echo $IAM: mkswap --label "$LABEL" --uuid "$UUID" "$DEVICE"
                mkswap --label "$LABEL" --uuid "$UUID" "$DEVICE"  >/dev/null 2>&1
                echo $IAM: sed -i "s/^UID=$UUID/LABEL=$LABEL/" "$FSTAB"
                sed -i "s/^UUID=$UUID/LABEL=$LABEL/" "$FSTAB"
        fi
done
swapon -a
```